# iframe src URL W3C validation error

Tags: validation, url, src, w3c-validation, percent-encoding

Every time I get an error when validating:

```
<iframe class="forecast" src="http://forecast.io/embed/&num;lat=-26.201560&amp;lon=28.038995&amp;name=Johannesburg,%20ZA&amp;text-color=&num;ffffff&amp;color=&num;ffffff&amp;font=Helvetica&amp;units=ca"></iframe>
```

Error (screenshot):
http://postimg.org/image/5h1kvzzuh/

I escaped the characters, but it didn't works.
Thanks.

Comment: Upvoted because this is a good catch and a good question given that I really should have the W3C validator emitting a more helpful message here—so it’s non-obvious what the particular problem is with the URL in that `src` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

W3C validator maintainer here. Short answer is, use instead the following:

```
<iframe class="forecast" src="http://forecast.io/embed/%23lat=-26.201560&amp;lon=28.038995&amp;name=Johannesburg,%20ZA&amp;text-color=&num;ffffff&amp;color=%23ffffff&amp;font=Helvetica&amp;units=ca"></iframe>
```

That is, the fix is just to replace `&num;` with **`%23`** (the [percent-encoding](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#percent-encode) of the `#` character).

#### Explanation

The specific problem in that URL is the `&num;` character references it contains.

`&num;` is `#` (the “number-sign” or “hash” character), which is not a [valid URL code point](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#url-code-points) per the URL Standard, and so it’s not allowed in a URL.

The `#` character is only ever allowed in an [*absolute URL with fragment*](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#syntax-url-absolute-with-fragment) or [*relative URL with fragment*](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#syntax-url-relative-with-fragment)—and then, explicitly allowed only *after* the part the URL spec defines as the actual URL.

And for the purposes of URLs, `&num;` and `#` are exactly the same.

Hence, you must use it as **`%23`** (that is, [percent-encoded](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#percent-encode)).

---

P.S. I plan to get the URL checker in the validator updated to actually report the particular illegal characters it finds in URLs but it will be a while yet before I can get that refinement made.